# Prove power rule

Tags: real-analysis

[Power Rule] Assume that $(e^x)'=e^x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ and $(\log x)' = \frac 1x$ for $x>0$. Use $x^\alpha := e^{\alpha \log x}$ to prove that $(x^\alpha)' = \alpha x^{\alpha - 1}$ for all $x>0$ and all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

Note I follow the train of thought here (EDIT)
$$\begin{split}
(x^\alpha)' &= (e^{\alpha \log x})' \\
&= (\alpha\log x)'(e^{ \log x^\alpha})\\
&= \alpha(\log x)'x^\alpha \\ 
&= \alpha x^{\alpha-1}.
\end{split}$$

I am assuming the question meant '$\log$' as $\ln$ with the usual base $e$.

Obviously I am thinking about this wrong. Any help is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\log x^{\alpha})'$ is not $\frac1{x^{\alpha}}$. That is your error. What you had been given was $(\log x)'=\frac1{x}$ and it's not OK to replace $x$ with $x^{\alpha}$.

But you could use logarithm rules to write $\log x^{\alpha}=\alpha\log x$ and go from there.

Comment: But then what would $(\alpha \log x)'$ be? I guess I use the product rule from here maybe, then It is shown easily?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a constant. Do you have the constant multiplier rule? $(\alpha\log x)'$ is $\alpha\cdot(\log x)'$.

Comment: I don't recall, but I am sure it is probably a pedestrian proof. Wait... the product rule does not apply, i forget because $\alpha$ is a constant. I will use the constant multiplier rule then.

Comment: Thanks @alex.jordan!